# my functions using args in python-telegram-bot do not work properly(so confused about it)

Tags: python, subprocess, args, python-telegram-bot

thank you for your attention i am totally confused about this:

here are two of my functions and commands but when I run the code bot doesn`t answer me
for example when I say '/cmd dir' or '/cmd ipconfig' or '/upload test.txt' nothing happen.

```
def cmd_method(bot , update , args):

        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        cmd = subprocess.check_output(args , shell = True)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id , cmd)



def upload_method(bot , update , args):

        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        document = open(args , "rb")
        bot.sendDocument(chat_id , document)
        document.close()


cmd = CommandHandler("cmd" , cmd_method , pass_args = True)
update.dispatcher.add_handler(cmd)

upload = CommandHandler("upload" , upload_method , pass_args=True )
update.dispatcher.add_handler(upload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the arguments in `CallbackContext.args` at python-telegram-bot v12.

```
import subprocess
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import Bot

def cmd_method(update, context):
    if context.args:
        cmd = subprocess.check_output(context.args, shell=True)
        update.message.reply_text("{!s}".format(cmd.strip().decode()))
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("You need to specify a command to execute")

def upload_method(update, context):
    if context.args:
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        document = open(context.args[0] , "rb")
        bot.sendDocument(chat_id , document)
        document.close()
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("You need to specify a file to upload")

update = Updater(tgtoken, use_context=True)
bot = Bot(tgtoken)

cmd = CommandHandler("cmd", cmd_method)
update.dispatcher.add_handler(cmd)
upload = CommandHandler("upload", upload_method)
update.dispatcher.add_handler(upload)

update.start_polling()
update.idle()
```